# SQLAlchemy DB not created on the filesystem

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Before closing this is a duplicate please review the issue.

I'm working through a python tutorial with the following ORM model.

```
from views import db
import datetime

class Task(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "tasks"

    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    due_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    priority = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, due_date, priority, status):
        self.name = name
        self.due_date = due_date
        self.priority = priority
        self.status = status

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<name {0}>'.format(self.name)
```

The config file is defined as follows:

```
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATABASE = 'flasktaskr.db'
USERNAME ='admin'
PASSWORD = 'admin'
CSRF_ENABLED = True # cross site request forgery prevention
SECRET_KEY = 'secret' # used in conjunction wth CSR
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.join(basedir, DATABASE)
SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + DATABASE_PATH
```

The view initializes the application as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('_config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Prior to executing the application the database has to be created using the following. The code runs with out exception, however the database is not created. I have trace the code and verified that the SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is set correct.

```
from views import db
from models import Task
from datetime import date

from models import Task


db.create_all()

db.session.add(Task("Finish this tutorial", date(2019, 6, 22), 10, 1))
db.session.add(Task("Finish Real Python", date(2019, 6, 25), 10, 1))

db.session.commit()
```

Based on this information what would prevent my database from being created on the filesystem?

Comment: Verify if typo are only in this post, or are in code too: SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI should be SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI (all capital letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify if typo are only in this post, or are in code too: SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI should be SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI (all capital letters